# how to create auto increment column with characters and number like alphanumeric in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

i have a table with primary key column which is auto-increment id of numerals starting from 1000..

now i have been asked to make a unique key for each records which starts with C20161, C20162, C20163 and so on the series goes on.....

so it is actually an alphanumeric key that auto-increments....

i would like to know how to implement the same in sql and also can i update the same to existing records?

is 'sequence' what i am looking for or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  [COMPUTED COLUMN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188300.aspx) for this purpose,

```
CREATE TABLE TableName(
     ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     NewColumnName AS 'C' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(30)),
     .... Other columns list here
)
```

Comment: just perfect!

actually i did an alter command as i had records in the dev (as well as live) table too...

here is what i executed and it was perfect

`ALTER TABLE CapDetailsByRH ADD cap_id AS 'C2016' + CAST(CapDetailsByRH_id AS VARCHAR(50))`

Comment: can i use the current year format? so it C2016 for this year, C2017 for the next and so on?

Is this good?
`ALTER TABLE CapDetailsByRH ADD cap_id AS 'C' +YEAR(getdate())+ CAST(CapDetailsByRH_id AS VARCHAR(50))`

Comment: Yes this look good and generic solution as well, Just need to cast this year in varchar so you can concatenate it as well

Comment: a small change in the request...
can we reset the id back to 1 when the new year falls?
so its C20161,C20162,C20163 and so on for current year,
 but the next year it should be C20171,C20172,C20173 and so on...is this possible in sql query or should i do it from my code?

(i know i cant use the above solution then as CapDetailsByRH_id gets incremented but is there another way?)

Comment: No this is not possible with current query, you may need Trigger for this purpose and and need to updated each record on insert, if you could do it from code then go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this is what you ask

first: i think you cant edit primary key.

second: if you want to update all existing data from int to varchar
then first you need to change your database.

after that try to use execute

example to update from 1001 to C1001

```
@key nvarhcar(5)
execute('update table set key = ''C' + @var1 +''' where key = @key')
```

now all you need is get the key
use for to get all key.

hope this help you